# Using Hibernate getCurrentSession().delete method delete the list of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to delete the list of Object with the `getCurrentSession().delete()` method. I found the optional way by writing the query like

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from Student where studentId =1").executeUpdate();
```

And I have come to another solution like

```
for (Student students : listOfStudents) {
    getCurrentSession().delete(student);
}
```

But it's not a database efficient call as it will create as many queries as the size of list. Is there any other efficient way to delete the list except writing a Hibernate query?

Comment: What's wrong with using the query solution that you first mentioned? Do you just not have the flexibility to compose the SQL?

Comment: I agree to writing HQL. But is there other way to delete the list?

Comment: I am not aware of such capability. I think what you are suggesting is this: put a bunch of entities in the session and then call a hibernate function to collectively delete all those entities in one SQL. The issue is that those entities could map to different tables in the DB. I think you can see the problem with that.